# I have 3 tasks and i want them to begin at the same time and run parallelly

Tags: c#, task

```
Task taskpro = new Task (delegate{codeblock});
Task taskbeds = new Task (delegate{codeblock});
Task taskpax = new Task (delegate{codeblock});

List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>(); 
TaskList.Add(taskBeds);
TaskList.Add(taskPro);
TaskList.Add(taskPax);

Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
```

In each code block i send request to different API. The thing is it takes a lot of time for APIs to return response if i send requests separately and i want to minimize waiting time.

Comment: you may want to use `await Task.WhenAll` instead in an async method. so if it takes a while it wont block UI thread and waiting is more bearable :)

Comment: So what's the problem?  You said it takes _"a lot of time"_ if you _"send requests separately"_ but you are **not sending them separately**.  You are already **potentially** sending them concurrently/parallel.   We won't know for sure without seeing more code

Comment: There's also [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: Parallel invoke seems like a way to go for me as the project is a c# .net application and this code executed in an action with others. Thanks for the idea i will try it out.

Comment: BTW, if you're making IO bound API calls (e.g. web), `delegate(codeblock)` should be changed to return a Task and make use of async/await patterns.

Comment: I don't see a call to the `Start` method.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use `new Task`. Use the `Task` returned from an async method, or if only sync methods are available, use `Task.Run`.

After that, wait for them all to complete asynchronously with `Task.WhenAll`.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<T>>();
tasks.Add(() => DoSomethingAsync());
tasks.Add(() => DoSomethingElseAsync());
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This is concurrency, not parallelism. It means they *can* run at the same time.